# Python HDF5 expand array

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to expand the dimensions of **<HDF5 dataset "time_data": shape (2048000, 63), type "<f4">** to shape **(2048000, 64)** . In the last column I'd like to add then the information from "<HDF5 dataset "time_data": shape (2048000, 1), type "<f4">". But I'm quite clueless how to do that.

So far I've tried:

```
mic['time_data'].resize(64, axis = 0)
```

But it  returns me a <HDF5 dataset "time_data": shape (64, 63), type "<f4">

I'm very new to HDF5 files, so please tell me if you need more information than I've given to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your post, I realized your dataset was resizable (otherwise h5py would have thrown an error on the resize). You can confirm by comparing  the `.shape` attribute to the `.maxshape` attribute. Note: `None` means no size limit on that axis.

[For future reference, if you want a resizable dataset, include the `maxshape=()` parameter when you create it. For this particular dataset, use `maxshape=(2048000, None)` if you only want to resize axis 1.]

Your unexpected result was caused by a small error in your resize declaration. To go from shape (2048000, 63) to shape (2048000, 64) it should be: `mic['time_data'].resize(64, axis=1)` or `mic['time_data'].resize((2048000, 64))`

**Updated answer**
Here is an expanded answer that shows how to add the the data from `'assembledH5Trigger.h5'` to `'assembledH5TEST.h5'`. For reference, it prints the `.shape` and `.maxshape` parameters before it copies the data from trigger to mic files.

```
with h5py.File('assembledH5TEST.h5', 'r+') as mic, \
     h5py.File('assembledH5Trigger.h5', 'r') as trigger:

    print(f"mic['time_data'] shape={mic['time_data'].shape}; " + \
          f" maxshape={mic['time_data'].maxshape}")          
    print(f"trigger['time_data'] shape={trigger['time_data'].shape}; " + \
          f"maxshape={trigger['time_data'].maxshape}")          
    mic['time_data'].resize((2048000, 64))
    mic['time_data'][:,63] = trigger['time_data'][:,0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I've solved it now. I didnt created the data by myself, so I dont't know how exactly it was created

Comment: Yeah, on second read, I realized your dataset was resizable. Otherwise you would have gotten an error. I added some code to my answer to show how to get the attributes AND how to read data from 1 file and append to a dataset in another file. This method is more memory efficient (important with large datasets)

Answer (score 0):

In the case somebody else has this problem as well in future. This is how I solved it (probably not a great solution, but it works):

```
    mic = h5py.File('assembledH5TEST.h5', "r+")
    trigger = h5py.File('assembledH5Trigger.h5', "r")


    arr = np.ones((2048000, 64))

    arr[:, 0:63] = mic["time_data"][:]
    arr[:,63] = trigger['time_data'][:,0]
    # Code to write arr to hdf5 file
```

Comment: Your method will work -- but a word of warning. You copy the data from both files into an intermediate array. That could be a problem with very large datasets. (The intermediate data is in memory.) HDF5 has advantages with "big data". It is designed to read "slices" of data from disc to RAM, so you can work with datasets that are larger than fit in RAM.